# Map data structure in pl/sql for storing key value pair?

Tags: plsql, dictionary, data-structures

Is there anyway to create a map data structure in pl/sql.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is the PL/SQL [associative array](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10472/composites.htm#CHDEIDIC)

```
DECLARE
  TYPE salary_tab_t IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30);
  salary_tab salary_tab_t;
BEGIN
  salary_tab('JONES') := 10000;
  salary_tab('SMITH') := 12000;
  salary_tab('BROWN') := 11000;
END;
```

You can loop through the elements like this:

```
  l_idx := salary_tab.FIRST;
  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN l_idx IS NULL;
    dbms_output.put_line (salary_tab(l_idx));
    l_idx := salary_tab.NEXT(l_idx);
  END LOOP;
```

Comment: Is this available with oracle 9i?

Comment: @yesraaj: Yes - see http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm#1059

Comment: Can you loop with this?

Comment: This was super helpful. Quick note for those trying to piece it together and who might not be familiar with PL/SQL: you'll need to define `l_idx varchar2(30)` up in the `DECLARE` block.  Other than that, you can directly copy/paste the loop code into the code block just before `END;`, and you'll have a working example.